# Router reusable scene with redux reducer

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-native-router-flux

I have a router `import { Scene, Router } from 'react-native-router-flux';` and I'm using the following navigation:

```
<Scene key="Home" title="home" icon={TabIcon}>
  <Scene tabs key="Categories" component={Categories} title="Categories" />
  <Scene tabs key="Objects" component={Objects} title="Objects" />
  <Scene tabs key="Object" component={ObjectContainer} title="Object" />
</Scene>
```

In this case the `Objects` trying to be a reusable scene, because when I click on a category and objects will shown there us subcategories, if i click on a subcategory there is objects and subcategories again. When I click on a object than shown the Object scene.

The flow: `Categories -> Objects -> Objects -> .... -> Objects -> Object`

That's fine. The problem, I want to use one redux reducer for the Objects, but when I click on the back button the previous tab will lose the data. In this case I never know what is the dept of the Objects, but somehow I have to store the all objects in all scenes.

I hope my problem is clear, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Do you want to keep all the objects ??

Comment: @Codesingh Not necessary, why?

Comment: you want to keep latest object(Categories -> Objects -> Objects -> .... -> Objects -> Object) navigated, in the redux store?

Comment: Yes, because if somebody click on the Object in the Objects list it will navigate to the object page.